# Flagging question for migration

Tags: discussion, support, migration

When flagging a question for migration to another site on the SE network, we get only 5 options as seen in the image below:

[image]

1. Why are only these 5 sites given preference?
2. How can I flag it to migrate to any other site than these?

Comment: Thanks Martijn. The first question is a duplicate. But, the second question I asked above is worth answering!

Comment: If you think a question really needs to be migrated to a site not listed, flag it as "other" and a moderator will migrate it for you.

Comment: @user4098326 I wouldn't be so sure about that because [they don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225006/add-a-dont-migrate-crap-migration-path-to-all-sites)

Comment: If a question is "crap", don't migrate it, just close it.